# JSF page set tab order dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

We have requirement to set the tab order dynamically on page based on below conditions.

If field has default value selected then that field should be skipped while user tabs. But if user explicitly clicks on default value field then next tab order should follow correctly by skipping the next default value fields. The fields which needs to be defaulted are decided on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could dynamically set the tabindex of the input fields, is that what you're trying to accomplish?  I'm not sure if tabindex is exposed as a JSF property or not.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp